# How to get more colors out of C++/Ncurses

Tags: c++, colors, ncurses

How do I get more than the 7 preset colors using the NCurses library with C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `colors` terminfo capability returns `8`, then you can't. If it returns a value higher than that then examine the result of the `cc` capability to see if you can change them via the `initc` capability.

Comment: Sorry, but could you go into a little more detail? I'm just a beginner trying to figure out NCurses. Thanks.

Comment: `tigetnum()` and `tigetflag()`.

Answer (score 2):

Some terminals allow you to change color definitions of the preset colors:

```
init_color(COLOR_RED, 900, 200, 200);
```

The first parameter is the color you want to change; the next three are the new RGB values of that color (all values must be between 0 and 1000). `can_change_color()` can tell you whether this is supported by your terminal.

Unfortunately, this automatically changes all instances of that color on the screen to the new color. So you can really only use 8 colors, even if you can choose what those 8 colors are.